# Mysql ERROR 1093 (HY000) updating a row

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table by updating the id of a row (id is auto increment). this is the code:

```
 update question_bank set id=1 where id=(select min(id) from question_bank where id>=1);
```

but I received this error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'question_bank' for update in FROM clause
```

What should I do?
Thanks :)

Comment: you should maybe not do this, or use the update with a join pattern (not that that helps with PK conflicts anyway)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: @Drew Can you comment the right form of the code. My knowledge about join pattern is not good!

Comment: not touching this one with a 10 foot pole: create table xxx ( id int auto_increment, theWhat varchar(80) not null );  Error 1075. Then PK conflict issues. To me, ids don't change. Sad orphaned children result. Granted, you could jam a key(id) at end. But what good is the auto_increment without it being primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ids are unique, you can use this:

```
update question_bank qb
    set id = 1
    where id >= 1
    order by id
    limit 1;
```

Or, you can use a `join`:

```
update question_bank qb join
       (select min(id) as minid from question_bank where id>=1) qb2
       on ab.id = qb2.minid
    set qb.id = 1;
```

Or, you can use a MySQL trick to get around this problem but using another level of subqueries:

```
update question_bank
    set id = 1
    where id = (select minid
                from (select min(id) as minid
                      from question_bank
                      where id >= 1
                     ) qb
               );
```